# Create an array in data file while the value in a specifc column is constant

Tags: scripts, sh

I have the follow data set:

```
M1  1   1233
M2  1   3212
M3  1   55323
M4  1   4444233
M5  1   23444
M6  1   555333
M7  1   55567
M8  2   22224
M9  2   55566
M10 2   4567
M11 3   44242
M12 3   234234
M13 4   2233
M14 4   2442
M15 4   322352
M16 4   235242
M17 4   2324524
M18 5   232342
M19 6   2322523
M20 6   2332523
```

and I want to create an array based on values of the second column. I want to apply other commands in all lines that have only 1 in the second column, after in lines that have 2 in the second column, and so on, and to save this in different files, but I don't know how to do this. I tried to use while command, but all my tentatives failed.

The outputs of this code should be subsets of the original file in each index of the array, for example:

index i1:

```
M1  1   1233
M2  1   3212
M3  1   55323
M4  1   4444233
M5  1   23444
M6  1   555333
M7  1   55567
```

index i2:

```
M8  2   22224
M9  2   55566
M10 2   4567
```

and so on a until

index i6:

```
M19 6   2322523
M20 6   2332523
```

Can you help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] and add the (or one exemplary) desired output.

Comment: Your data is already sorted by the proposed index number. You can simply read the file and change processing when column 2 changes. Using indices just complicates your project I think.

Comment: Crossposted here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/530132/create-an-array-in-data-file-while-the-value-in-a-specifc-column-is-constant

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the requirement correctly, something roughly like this should work:

```
data="M1  1   1233
M2  1   3212
M3  1   55323
M4  1   4444233
M5  1   23444
M6  1   555333
M7  1   55567
M8  2   22224
M9  2   55566
M10 2   4567
M11 3   44242
M12 3   234234
M13 4   2233
M14 4   2442
M15 4   322352
M16 4   235242
M17 4   2324524
M18 5   232342
M19 6   2322523
M20 6   2332523
"
echo "$data" | while read ln; do
    set -- $ln
    echo $ln >> i$2
done
```